# How to schedule multiple posts while adding new

Tags: posts, date-time

In a WordPress powered news portal, they need to upload many news at a time on a certain period of a day, in most of the cases, after 10pm (*today*). But they are actually inserting news for the next day (*tomorrow*). So in WordPress way they need to schedule the news (post) each time when publishing.

[image: scheduling a post]

The same repeating job - edit the time, change the date to the upcoming date (i.e. 19), change the Hour to 12, and Minute to 01. That's time consuming and a bit of disturbing too.

Is there a way I can make a common thing for them so that they can set it once and upload all the posts to the newly set time? And can reset the timing anytime?

Comment: If I understand well: you want that default behaviour is to schedule posts instead of publishing them immediately and that the date / time of schedule should be configurable sitewide. Am I right?

Comment: No, that may always NOT the case. Because sometimes they may need to publish an article immediately. I think it'd better if we think a chunk of posts to be scheduled but not all. Or, whether can it be done by creating a session when to schedule for a certain period?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a **sketch** of another idea, where we create **scheduling shortcuts** to make it easier for the users:

[image: scheduling shortcuts]

We can use the `post_submitbox_misc_actions` to add extra fields to the *submit box*:

```
/**
 * Scheduling-Shortcuts fields.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/168748/26350
 */

add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', function() {

    if( ! current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) 
        return;
?>
    <div style="padding: 2px 10px;">
        <h4><?php _e( 'Scheduling shortcuts:' ); ?></h4>
        <ul class="schedule-shortcuts">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" value="current" 
                       name="wpse_schedule_shortcut" 
                       id="shcedule-shortcut-0" checked="checked" />
                <label for="shcedule-shortcut-0"><?php _e( 'Current settings' );?></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" value="tomorrow_at_12"   
                       name="wpse_schedule_shortcut" id="shcedule-shortcut-1" />
                <label for="shcedule-shortcut-1"><?php _e( 'Tomorrow @12' );?></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'schedule_shortcut_action','schedule_shortcut_field'); ?>
    </div>
<?php
});
```

where we can then modify the *insert post data* accordingly via the `wp_insert_post_data` filter:

```
/**
 * Scheduling-Shortcuts post data handling.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/168748/26350
 */

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', function( $data, $postarr ) {

    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return $data;

    if( ! current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )
        return $data; 

    if( ! isset( $postarr['post_type'] ) || 'post' !== $postarr['post_type'] )
        return $data;

    if( ! isset( $postarr['action'] ) || 'editpost' !== $postarr['action'] )
        return $data;

    if ( ! isset( $postarr['schedule_shortcut_field'] ) 
         || !wp_verify_nonce($postarr['schedule_shortcut_field'],'schedule_shortcut_action')
    ) 
        return $data;

    if( isset( $postarr['wpse_schedule_shortcut'] ) 
        && 'tomorrow_at_12' === $postarr['wpse_schedule_shortcut'] 
    )
    {
        $data['post_status']     = 'future';
        $data['post_date']       = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s',   strtotime( "+1 day 00:00" ) );
        $data['post_date_gmt']   = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( "+1 day 00:00" ) );
    }       
    return $data;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Hopefully you can adjust this further to your needs.

Comment: This is a good one. But how to get rid of the undefined index generating from `if( 'editpost' !== $postarr['action'] ) return $data;`?

Comment: ahh, please check out the update ;-)

Comment: `add_action()`'s ending tags are not ended correctly. ...After scheduling posts in this way when I changed the PC date, they got published - everthing's ok. But why the `Missed schedule` warning is there always ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/fhKfEt4.png))?

Comment: Pardon me please. But did you get time to have a look?

Comment: Please check the updated answer @MayeenulIslam

Comment: Something is prohibiting the scheduled publication (see: http://prntscr.com/59w7af). I scheduled 2 posts to 25th, I checked the server time (see: http://prntscr.com/59w7l9), it's passed 12AM, but not publishing the posts. I failed in localhost yesterday, so I checked it in a server (http://sntbdhost.net/dev/) - the two scheduled posts are till scheduled. BTW your previous code worked well in this matter only was showing the 'Missed schedule' warning.

Comment: I just tested the scheduling on my install and it worked there.  For testing I changed "+1 day 12:00" to "+10 minutes". I first see the *2014/11/27 11:13:39 AM
Scheduled* label and then the *2014/11/27 11:13:39 AM
Published* label, no *Missed Schedule*. Maybe it matter that I'm on the GMT+0 timezone?

Comment: IS the PERFECT answer now. Thanks a lot @birgire for your time and effort. It's working excellent now after I've changed the hour from `12:00` to `00:00`. Thank you soo much. :)

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, got a temporary solution, suggested by one of my non-WP colleague, Mr. Shamim. And tested in WP 4.0 with success — **It's the bulk publish from drafts**.

[image: bulk draft selection to edit]

[image: bulk publish multiple drafts]

The idea is, whatever the series of posts or bunch of posts are to publish, first save 'em as a draft. Then on the time, *when it's time*, check all of them in a bunch, choose Edit from the `Bulk Actions` dropdown menu, and then on the expanded panel, choose "Published" from the status, and finally hit **Update**.

But it has one drawback, you have to come back to the post list when you want to publish them all.