# Any way to create scheduled post programatically?

Tags: scheduled-posts

I'm searching through the web for any solutions that will allow me to create a post programatically with post status : Future (Scheduled Post).

I'm reading through **wp_schedule_event** WordPress function for creating cron jobs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about your context, but we dealt with scheduled posts a few days ago, and @birgire did an excellent job done. [Have a look](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/168728/22728) if it may answer you. :)

Answer (score 6):

I found my answer while searching over other stackoverflow answers below is the code what I've added.

```
$postdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+20 minutes'));
$postdate_gmt = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($postdate));

$post = array(
    'post_date_gmt'  => $postdate_gmt,
    'post_date'  => $postdate,
    'edit_date' => 'true'
);
```