# Use touch_time() on front-end form via plugin

Tags: plugins, templates, date-time

I'm working on a plug-in that let people create posts from front-end form. I want to add date&time fields in the form using `touch_time()` but don't know how to use it on front-end.

I have `<div id="timestampdiv" class="hide-if-js"><?php touch_time(0, 0, 5); ?></div>` on the front-end form which giving me an error message `Fatal error: Call to undefined function touch_time()`.

Is it possible to access `touch_time` function([wp-admin/includes/template.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/touch_time/)) from my plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try to include the the `template.php` file:

```
<?php 
if( ! function_exists( 'touch_time' ) )
{
    require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/template.php' );
    touch_time( 0, 0, 5 ); 
}
?>
```

but I think it might be better to just copy the code from the `touch_time()` function into your own function and modify accordingly.

*Friday part of the answer:*

### "A Big Mess" and "Black Magic"

According to the inline documentation, that file is a **Big Mess** ;-)

```
/**
 * Template WordPress Administration API.
 *
 * A Big Mess. Also some neat functions that are nicely written.
 *
```

and watch out for the **Black Magic** in the `/wp-includes/rewrite.php` file:

```
 /**
  * Generate rewrite rules from a permalink structure.
  *
  * The main WP_Rewrite function for building the rewrite rule list. The
  * contents of the function is a mix of black magic and regular expressions,
  * so best just ignore the contents and move to the parameters.
  *
```

so be aware what you include in your plugin ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would you mind explaining why it's better to copy the code from `touch_time()`? Your code brings the time form in my front-end form but it does not actually update the time in DB.

Comment: This function only displays the form and doesn't contain  the update code. This is also specific to the back-end so it might not suit your needs on the front-end, like the OK and Cancel parts. It might also change in the future? @Ohsik

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! that cleared lots of things for me :) Now I have to find a way to process that Date/Time values ;)

Comment: you're welcome and good luck with your project. @Ohsik